Seams in USGS 3DEP 1m data
I'm working with USGS 3DEP 1m elevation data from lidar to find sinkholes across the state of Florida. Unfortunately, the data isn't seamless - the elevation has sharp changes that don't correspond to the real topography. That problem can be seen with this code; it's the Earth Engine example - I've only changed the center and visualization scale.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USGS/3DEP/1m');
var visualization = {
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  palette: [
    '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f', 'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13',
    'ff6e08', 'ff500d', 'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', '0602ff', '235cb1',
    '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef', '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f'
  ],
};
Map.setCenter(-82.8, 30.0, 10);
Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, 'elevation');

Elevation discontinuity
I assume these discontinuities are at data collection boundaries, but they cause problems with my analysis.
The 10 meter data  on Earth Engine doesn't have this problem.
I believe that the USGS 3DEPDEM viewer at https://apps.nationalmap.gov/3depdem/ uses the same 1 meter base data, but it doesn't have this problem. I've tried different CRS transforms of the data tiles retrieved by Earth Engine, but the discontinuity boundaries don't align with the data tiles, so this had no effect.
USGS states that the 1 meter data is "project based" while the 1/3 arc second/10 meter data is "seamless".
I'd like to have 1 meter seamless data, like the USGS viewer. Is there a way to apply that correction?
